# Include Objects Passed Bounds In Screenshot

Tags: objective-c, uiview, screenshot, bounds

I have a UIView that has over 100 objects rendered in it (UIImages, labels, text, etc.)

I am trying to take a screenshot of the UIView, however some of the objects within the view are past the bounds of the view. I wanted to know if there is some way to either specify a graphics context + "some distance" in order to include these objects, or perhaps a way to make the graphics context size appropriately to include the furthest object out of the bounds. Thanks for any help